# How to split comma separated numbers using a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a long, comma-separated list which looks like this in Excel:

```
481703472.963,2761810387.418,34630.525
481703472.963,2761810387.418,34630.526
481703472.963,2761810387.418,34630.527
```

I need a **formula** to convert this into Six separate columns.

It should look like as per image:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to keep the commas at the end of the values in column2 and column4. Data, Text to Columns, Fixed width seems like it should do this.

Comment: I basically do not need values from the columns 2,4&6. I am aware that I can get those values from Data, Text to Columns......
But I have asked for FORMULA if any.

Comment: @user1099330,, are you looking for the output as #Máté Juhász uploaded or simply looking to split into columns using multiple delimiters ??

Comment: Why column 5 have specific values which not include in sample list?

Comment: @Lee.... I just want to know the Formula (if any). we can ignore exact values, take these values as example.

Comment: @Rajesh S..... I just want to simply split the values, using Formula. Thanks,

Comment: @user1099330,, then please [Edit] the post & show the exact output as you are in need of,,  or mention that what has been posted by #Máté Juhász is the expected output!!

Answer (score 0):

*This can be fixed even using built in `Text to Column` command.*

**Caveat:**

- *@Máté Juhász edited the posted, as well uploaded the required output after this solution have been posted.*
- *My solution addresses original issue as shown with `Before split captioned picture`.*

**Before split:**

[image]

---

- From **D**ata TAB hit **T**ext To Column.
- Select **D**elimited Option.
- Move to Next screen.
- Now Check **C**omma & **O**ther Check box.
- Insert `.` symbol for **O**ther Text box.
- Finally hit **F**inish.

[image]

---

*You get this after split:*

[image]

**N.B.** Just for better look I've Bold faced the Cells `T1` & `T2`, you may ignore this.

---

**Edited:**

*I'm posting this solution based on Excel Formula, since OP is in need of `simple split into columns, confirmed through comments below`.*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `V8` & fill it across:

  `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("."&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($T8,",","."),",","."),",","."),".",REPT(" ",50)),50*COLUMNS($T:T),50))`

*Adjust cell reference and delimiters in the formula as needed.*

Comment: it's not the same output as required in the picture in the question.

Comment: I basically do not need values from the columns U,W&Y. I am aware that I can get those values from Data, Text to Columns.. as you suggested ...... But I have asked for FORMULA if any plz.

Comment: @user1099330,, this can be fixed using a Formula or even by VBA macro,, but I've suggested simple one because I do believe that we should avoid the complicated method as long as possible ,, please [Edit] your post and bottom line your need i.e. FORMULA ONLY,,  !!

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, every problem have has a solution and so did this specific issue does have,, you have  edited the post after I've posted the answer,,, unfortunate getting Down Vote !!

Comment: @MátéJuhász & Rajesh S..... I need Formula plz.

Comment: @user1099330,,I can show you formula splits the text into columns ,, by Delimiters,, but not as shown  with the OP (edited),, but simple split like ,, `481703472 963 2761810387 418 34630 525` ,confirm through comments!!

Comment: @Rajesh S... Yes, please share.

Comment: @user1099330,, now check the edited part,, I've posted the solution based on Excel Formula,, please [Edit] the question and show the expected output to avoid any further confusion.

Comment: @Rajesh S.... You are Genius. thanks a lot. Your advised excel formula worked perfectly.....

Comment: @user1099330,,  glad to help you ,, now you may accept it as Answer as well up Vote also ☺

Answer (score 0):

If you need just a few columns and number of digits is always the same, then just use `MID()`:

`=MID($A2,10,5)`

[image]

Comment: These are not a smart formula since for  every piece of data `Start` & `Num Of Characters` need to be changed !! And OP was looking for simple split just check the comments below my post .

Answer (score 0):

If, as you wrote above, you are only interested in returning the values showing in columns `1,3,5`, you can try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),-1+FIND(".",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)))),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

Where `seq_99` is a **Named Formula** that refers to:

```
=IF(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,255,1))=1,1,(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,255,1))-1)*99)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Since the August 2022 Excel release](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/what-s-new-in-excel-august-2022/ba-p/3590457), you can do this with the `TEXTSPLIT` function. From the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7):

> Splits text strings by using column and row delimiters.
>
> The TEXTSPLIT function works the same as the Text-to-Columns wizard,
> but in formula form. It allows you to split across columns or down by
> rows. It is the inverse of the TEXTJOIN function.

Basic syntax is `=TEXTSPLIT(text,col_delimiter,[row_delimiter],[ignore_empty],[match_mode],[pad_with])` (where bracketed arguments are optional) and your formula will spill over to the cells to the right and below according to your input (same way the Text-to-Columns wizard would). If any of the cells that would be occupied by the formula output is not empty, or merged, [you'll get a `#SPILL!` error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-spill-error-ffe0f555-b479-4a17-a6e2-ef9cc9ad4023).